# Mounted .img file does not clear up disk space when files are deleted

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, mount, mkfs

I have a requirement to use more inodes than normally available on most file systems. Therefore, I create and mount a ext4 filesystem with a custom inode setting:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=loop0.img bs=1MB count=5000
losetup --find --show `pwd`/loop0.img
mkfs -t ext4 -i 1024 /dev/loop0
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

This will create a 5000MB file on the disk (via `ls /mnt`), but when I check using `df` it shows as the disk is not occupied (disk space does not go up by 5000MB ). I suspect because it's zeroed out on the disk and looks like unused space.

As the disk gets full, I have a program that tries to delete least-recently-used files until the disk space pressure is removed. Well it turns out that despite deleting the files in `/mnt`, it still registers as taking up space on my disk, at least according to `df` and other disk free system calls.

So is there a special way I need to `rm` the files on this virtual disk in order to register that the space is free? or do I need to inquire about free space in a non-standard way?

Edit: The full command and output, notice that the disk usage for `/dev/vda1` does not increase 5000MB.

```
root@localhost:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              490064       0    490064   0% /dev
tmpfs             101092    3188     97904   4% /run
/dev/vda1       19343152 2699088  15660656  15% /
tmpfs             505448       0    505448   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             505448       0    505448   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             101088       0    101088   0% /run/user/0
root@localhost:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=loop0.img bs=1MB count=5000
5000+0 records in
5000+0 records out
5000000000 bytes (5.0 GB, 4.7 GiB) copied, 6.20117 s, 806 MB/s
root@localhost:~# losetup --find --show `pwd`/loop0.img
/dev/loop0
root@localhost:~# mkfs -t ext4 -i 1024 /dev/loop0
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 1220703 4k blocks and 4884000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 4f308a54-6ddd-4ef6-b685-c193dfec8b84
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        8176, 24528, 40880, 57232, 73584, 204400, 220752, 400624, 662256,
        1022000

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

root@localhost:~# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
root@localhost:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              490064       0    490064   0% /dev
tmpfs             101092    3216     97876   4% /run
/dev/vda1       19343152 2769404  15590340  16% /
tmpfs             505448       0    505448   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             505448       0    505448   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             101088       0    101088   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       3594900   45080   3289556   2% /mnt
```

Comment: Note that when you use `dd if=/dev/zero` without `conv=sparse` to create the image, how much the filesystem usage (of the filesystem that consists of the image) will be increased is probably filesystem-specific. If you would like the image to be a sparse file anyway, you can simply use `truncate` to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fstrim`:

```
$ rm /tmp/test.img
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/test.img': No such file or directory
$ truncate -s 1G /tmp/test.img
$ sudo losetup --show -f /tmp/test.img 
/dev/loop0
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -E root_owner=1000:1000 /dev/loop0
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 262144 4k blocks and 65536 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 70f9b205-0ada-43b1-8636-36983ad79394
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/meh/
$ openssl enc -pbkdf2 -aes-256-ctr -in /dev/zero -pass file:/dev/urandom -nosalt 2>/dev/null | dd of=/tmp/meh/fill iflag=count_bytes count=768M
1572864+0 records in
1572864+0 records out
805306368 bytes (805 MB, 768 MiB) copied, 2.15669 s, 373 MB/s
$ sudo umount /tmp/meh/
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/meh/
$ rm /tmp/meh/fill 
$ sudo umount /tmp/meh/
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/meh/
$ du -h /tmp/test.img 
802M    /tmp/test.img
$ sudo fstrim -v /tmp/meh/
/tmp/meh/: 973.4 MiB (1020678144 bytes) trimmed
$ du -h /tmp/test.img 
33M /tmp/test.img
```

The unused (in terms of the filesystem on the image) space will be converted into "holes" (in the [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) sense).

As you may have guessed, you can mount with `-o discard` as well -- just note that the result might be slightly delayed.